# Can anyone explain the difference between the numbers of install on Playstore and Console? ( Images included)

Tags: android, google-developers-console

can anyone explain the difference between these figures?

[from Playstore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKjmK.jpg)

[From Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8vLb.png)

Comment: Is one lifetime and the other current?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any difference in the time you took the screenshots between the two?
The playstore displays the lifetime downloads of your application and works in range as follows:

```
1+ (1 - 5)
5+ (6 - 10)
10+ (11 - 50)
50+ (51 - 100)
100+ (101 - 500)
500+ (501 - 1000)
1000+ (1001 - 5000)
5000+ (5001 - 10000)
10000+ (10001 - 50000)
50000+ (50001–100000)
100000+ (100001–500000)
500000+ (500001–1000000)
1000000+ (1000001–5000000)
5000000+ (5000001–10000000)
10000000+ (10000001–50000000)
50000000+ (50000001–100000000)
100000000+ (100000001–500000000)
500000000+ (500000001–1000000000)
1000000000+ (1000000001–5000000000)
```

but when you display the report on your google play console you can configure your report from weeks to 365 days and, you can also put a customer timeline so you can have a detailed report.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwKsB.png)